# Abrir uma activity ao clicar em um item de uma list view

Tags: java, android

Eu tou meio perdido já, quero que quando clicar em um item da lista ele abra outra activity, porém só consigo toast... sou iniciante então se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

```
public class estatisticas extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_estatisticas);
    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("a", 1);

    final ListView lista =  findViewById(R.id.Listview);
    final ArrayList<String> estatisticas = preencherdados();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, estatisticas);
    lista.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            estatisticas artilheiros = (estatisticas) lista.getItemAtPosition(1);
            Intent it = new Intent(estatisticas.this, artilheiros.class);
            startActivity(it);
            it.putExtra("a", position = 1);
        }
    });


}

private ArrayList<String> preencherdados() {
    ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>();

    dados.add("TOP 15 ARTILHEIROS");
    dados.add("Campeões");
    return dados;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Devo supor que sua intenção era passar a posição pelo Intent, porém você esta iniciando a activity antes de passar o dado pelo Intent, o correto é chamar putExtra() antes de iniciar a activity, isso deve resolver:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent it = new Intent(estatisticas.this, artilheiros.class);
            it.putExtra("a", position);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

Uma boa prática é não criar classes que comecem com letras minúsculas como descrito [pela oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e o nome deve ser o mesmo do seu arquivo .java, isso ajuda a manter a legibilidade do seu código fonte.

**Editado**

Se você deseja abrir uma activity para o item clicado então basta usar `position` que retorna a posição do item na lista, quando você atribui o valor 1 em `position = 1` sempre vai ser o item que estiver na posição 1 da lista.

Comment: eu consegui, porem se na minha listview tem 2 itens ou mais, quando eu clicar nos 2 sai a mesma coisa, queria que fosse 1 pra cada, sabe? :/

Comment: @vitu tente agora

Comment: Não entendi direito, pode me explicar de novo? seria retornar o "position"? isso eu tentei e não deu certo, talvez tenha tentado errado

Comment: @vitu position retorna é a posição do item que você clicou na lista, exemplo se sua lista tem 3 elementos e você clica no segundo ele vai retornar 1, se clica no primeiro 0, se no terceiro 2, o problema é que você esta atribuindo 1 em putExtra, ou seja ele sempre vai retornar a segunda posição da lista

Answer (score -1):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //aqui vc irá fazer a acao com o click pegando uma posicao da sua lista, coloquei um exemplo de iniciar uma nova tela passando o item clicado por parametro.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MinhaProximaTela.class);
            intent.putExtra("mParametro", mParametro[position]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```